# C# MAPI to read exchange server inbox

Tags: c#, exchange-server, mapi

I want to write C# application which will remotely connect to exchange server and read my inbox! I want to use MAPI for that.

So I got two questions:

1. Can it be done remotely, and is there any requirements(e.g. install outlook client,etc? )
2. I was not able to find any code example in C# which uses MAPI to connect to inbox?

Answer (score 3):

1) If I remember correctly Outlook must be installed and a profile must be set up. (In short; you are reading Outlooks data, not Exchange).

2) There are samples for this:

- http://bytes.com/topic/net/insights/795371-accessing-inbox-through-mapi-using-c-net
- http://g8.cx/mapi/ (See 4.7)

Note that [MAPI/CDO is not supported in .Net.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mstehle/archive/2007/10/03/fyi-why-are-mapi-and-cdo-1-21-not-supported-in-managed-net-code.aspx)

Other options is to communicate directly using WebDAV, IMAP, POP3 or [WebServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx). All will work to retrieve emails. I recommend you try the webservice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please provide some more information about web services, information regarding to pros and cons of using web services? 1) Does it support all versions of exchange server or only 2010? 2) Does user(where my application will run) need to enable some web services or install anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the mailbox of a user from a remote machine.The email account should be configured on that machine and then you can read the mailbox using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook and this link will provide you more info.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff870566.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use MAPI so badly ?

Just use EWS:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399015/Exchange-Web-Services