# How to download an excel attachment from outlook inbox and save the data to sql server in C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, console-application

I want to to download an excel attachment from outlook inbox (saving it in the application folder) and then save the data of excel sheet to sql server table in C# Console Application. Could you help me in achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think we may help... but we won't do the job for you. Tried anything already ?

Comment: I don't know how to get started...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have two ways: calling Outlook that's installed on client computer and calling server (Exchange?) for this.

Outlook way. First you need to logon. Read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869819.aspx about it. Then read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863719.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff870432 . Yes, some examples are in VB, you'd have to translate them into C#.
Also take a look here [C# MAPI to read exchange server inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065017/c-sharp-mapi-to-read-exchange-server-inbox)

Exchange way. Search google for `IMAP C# example`.

To save to SQL Server you need to create table with a BLOB field and insert data into it, for example, via ADO.NET. Search google for `ADO.NET` and `ADO.NET blob` and surely you'd get many examples.